# Универсальные функции

Tags: c, функции

Можно ли на языке С написать универсальную функцию? 
Например, функция которая может складывать числа типа int, float, double и тд или функция, которая ищет максимальный элемент в массиве произвольного типа. Если да, то можете привести пример.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал посмотреть, что такое *обобщенные селекторы* (`_Generic`).

Comment: На языке С можно написать все, что угодно. Но для этого надо сначала понять, что именно нужно. Что такое "сумма" в контексте данного вопроса? Что такое сумма двух строк? Что такое сумма двух массивов? О чем вообще идет речь?

Comment: например, 1 + 2 = 3 или  1.0 + 2.0 = 3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Функцию*, которая напрямую работает с разными (несовместимыми) типами аргументов в таких достаточно строго типизированных языках, как С или С++ написать в общем случае невозможно. Для более-менее элегантного решения подобных задач язык С++ предоставляет такие механизмы, как полиморфизм времени выполнения, перегрузка функции и/или шаблоны функций. В последних двух вариантах вы получаете не функцию, а набор функций, либо явно определенных вами, либо неявно генерируемых для вас компилятором.

В языке С таких механизмов на уровне ядра языка нет (или они недоступны пользователю). Однако на языке С вы их можете эмулировать с той или иной степенью похожести или удобства

1. Универсальная функция поиска максимального элемента массива может быть реализована в С на основе полиморфизма времени выполнения через callback-компаратор, точно так же, как это делается в стандартных функциях `qsort` или `bsearch`

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int cmp_int(const void *l, const void *r)
   {
     int li = *(const int *) l, ri = *(const int *) r;
     return (li > ri) - (li < ri);
   }

   int cmp_double(const void *l, const void *r)
   {
     double li = *(const double *) l, ri = *(const double *) r;
     return (li > ri) - (li < ri);
   }

   void *max_element(const void *a, size_t n, size_t size, 
                     int cmp(const void *, const void *))
   {
     const void *max = a;

     if (n > 0)
       while (--n > 0)
       {
         a = (const char *) a + size;
         if (cmp(max, a) < 0)
           max = a;
       }

     return (void *) max;
   }

   int main()
   {
     const int a[] = { 1, 2, 8, 7, 3, 2, 5 };
     const int *max_i = max_element(a, sizeof a / sizeof *a, sizeof *a, cmp_int);
     printf("%d\n", *max_i);

     const double b[] = { 1., 2., 8., 7., 3., 2., 5. };
     const double *max_d = max_element(b, sizeof b / sizeof *b, sizeof *b, cmp_double);
     printf("%lf\n", *max_d);
   }
   ```
2. Механизмы перегрузки или шаблонов можно эмулировать через макросы, либо напрямую реализуя требуемую функциональность макросом, либо используя макросы для инстанцирования требуемых версий функций (с разными названиями, разумеется)

   ```
   #define COMPARE(l, r) (((l) > (r)) - ((l) < (r)))

   #define DEFINE_COMPARATOR(T, suffix)\
     int cmp_##suffix(const void *l, const void *r)\
     {\
        const T *lhs = l, *rhs = r;\
        return COMPARE(*lhs, *rhs);
     }

   ...
   DEFINE_COMPARATOR(int, int)
   DEFINE_COMPARATOR(double, double)
   ```
3. Пользуясь функциональностью `_Generic` (либо самостоятельно, либо вкупе с пунктом 2) во многих случаях в С можно реализовать достаточно точное подобие перегрузки функций из С++, т.е. свести несколько разных функций под один "диспетчер" вызовов.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #define DEFINE_ADD(T, suffix) T add_##suffix(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }

   DEFINE_ADD(int, int)
   DEFINE_ADD(double, double)

   #define add(lhs, rhs) _Generic((lhs) + (rhs),\
     int : add_int,\
     double : add_double)((lhs), (rhs))

   int main()
   {
     int a = 1, b = 5;
     double c = 4.0, d = 8.5;
     printf("%d %lf\n", add(a, b), add(c, d));
   }
   ```